# "Motzi Matzah" or "Motzi and Matzah" (separately)? Passover Seder

Tags: minhag, number, passover-seder-hagada, matzah, hamotzi-beracha

In some haggadot, I have seen the numbers of sections as being 14, with Motzi Matzah being combined, and in other haggadot, I have seen 15 with them separated. What is the reason behind each side?

Comment: I have heard that there must be 15 steps to the seder because 15 is gematria Yud-Hei (God's name), and the seder is holy so it must be 15.  However, if they are separate steps, then motzi requires a kezayit, matzah requires a kezayit, and tzafun (afikoman) requires a kezayit.  Maybe according to those who require two matzot at the table hold that motzi-matzah is combined, and those who require three hold that they are not combined.

Comment: what are the links to the mi yodeya questions #14 and #15 so that we can submit this to there?

Comment: I've seen at least one haggadah that listed them separately in the list at the beginning (to get 15) but combined them in the section header when you get there.  I don't remember which haggadah this was; I'll try to remember to check the ones I own when I get home later to see if it's one of them.

Comment: @AdamMosheh in that case perhaps there are 26 steps to the Seder. Time to get creative and make up steps?

Comment: Not make up.  They would already exist, but be hidden.  Maybe motzi is really shem+malchut+hamotzi.  How many permutations there are of Hashem's name and a lot of halachot that could be counted as steps to the seder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically what's happening at this stage is that you make two blessings, 'hamotzi' and 'al akhilas matza' and then eat one portion for each blessing. The side that puts it all together might do so because both blessings/portions are being done at once. The other side would say that since it's really two steps, they should be split.

Comment: Why the downvotes?